# Вытягивания виджетов

Tags: c++, qt, gui, qt5, интерфейс

Я работаю в `qt5`. Эта кнопка("addButton") [image: введите сюда описание изображения] отвечает за создание этих кнопок("GreenButton") [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. В слоте *addButton* создается *GreenButton*:

```
void SearchForm::on_AddButtonButton_pressed()
{
     Editor.pobj = new GreenButton(this);
}
```

Код *GreenButton*:

```
QPoint delta;

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
        {
            delta.rx()   = e->pos().x();
            delta.ry()   = e->pos().y();
        }

        void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
        {

            setGeometry(
                    geometry().x()  + e->pos().x() - delta.x(),
                    geometry().y()  + e->pos().y() - delta.y(),
                    width(),
                    height()
            );
        }

        explicit GreenButton(QWidget *parent = 0 ) 
        {


            setGeometry(QCursor::pos().x() - parent->geometry().x() - 8,
                        QCursor::pos().y() - parent->geometry().y() - 8,
                        111,
                        111
            );
            show();
            QMouseEvent event1(QEvent::MouseButtonPress,  this->pos(), Qt::LeftButton,Qt::LeftButton,Qt::NoModifier);

            QApplication::sendEvent(this, &event1);
        }
```

*GreenButton* создается , перемещается мышью. Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на *addButton* и не отпускании ее перемещался *GreenButton*?
Я думал поможет искуственное создание событий, но не помогло:

```
QMouseEvent event1(QEvent::MouseButtonPress,  this->pos(), Qt::LeftButton,Qt::LeftButton,Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::sendEvent(this, &event1);
```

Comment: У вас объект `event1` создан на стеке, и соответственно разрушается при выходе из функции. Попробуйте создать его в куче.

Comment: а мне и не нужно обращаться  в "event1" поза "explicit GreenButton(QWidget *parent = 0 ) "

Comment: сделал на куче, не помогло

Comment: Тогда может попробовать использовать функцию `QApplication::postEvent(QObject * receiver, QEvent * event)`?

Comment: Или после вызова `show()` перед созданием и отправкой своего события вызывать `QApplication::processEvents()`, чтобы ваша `GreenButton` отрисовалась.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала решение:

```
class MyForm: public QWidget
{
     QTimer      * Ticker      ;
     QPushButton * MovingButton;

public:
     MyForm(QWidget * parent = nullptr)
        : QWidget     (parent )
        , Ticker      (nullptr)            
        , MovingButton(nullptr)
     {
         Ticker = new QTimer(this);
         connect(Ticker, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyForm::moveButton);
     }

     ~MyForm() 
     {
        stopMoving();
     }

public slots:
     void addPressed()
     {
         MovingButton = new QPushButton(this);
         // настраиваем новую кнопку
         MovingButton->show();

         // Начинаем перемещение через пол секунды
         Ticker->setSigngleShot(true);
         Ticker->setInterval(500);
         Ticker->start();
     }

     void addReleased()
     { 
         stopMoving(); // останавливаем движение
     }

     void moveButton()
     {
         if(MovingButton)
         {
            if(Ticker->singleShot())  // ускоряем таймер до 30 мс
            {
               Tciker->setSignleShot(false);
               Ticker->setInterval(30); 
            }

            // двигаем кнопку
            MovingButton->move(MovingButton->pos() + QPoint(8,8));
         }
     }

private:
     void stopMoving()
     {
         MovingButton = nullptr;
         Ticker->stop();
     }
};
```

Здесь `addPressed()` и `addReleased()` слоты которые должны быть подключены с сигналам кнопки `AddButton` `pressed()` и `released()` соответственно.

Работает код следующим образом:

- В обработчике нажатия `addPressed()` создаем новую кнопку и запоминаем указатель на нее в `MovingButton`, потом стартуем таймер `Ticker` на пол секунды по окончании которого выполняем перемещение. Пол секунды нужно для того чтобы была пауза перед началом движения.
- В обработчике таймера `Ticker` `moveButton()` ускоряем таймер до 30 мс а также перемещаем текущую кнопку `MovingButton` если таковая имеется.
- В обработчике отпускания `addRelease()` просто зануляем указатель на перемещаемую кнопку `MovingButton` и останавливаем таймер `Ticker` - таким образом останаваливаем движение.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. у нас есть форма, на которой размещена «добавляющая кнопка», и на ту же форму мы добавляем другие кнопки, предлагаю воспользоваться следующей стратегией:

1. Устанавливаем фильтр сообщений на нашу «добавляющую» кнопку. Будем ловить нажатие и перемещение мыши.
2. Во время нажатия будем создавать новую кнопку и запоминать её.
3. Во время появления события перемещения, будем перемещать нашу кнопку.
   Всё это довольно просто реализовать:

**MainWindow.h**:

```
#pragma once

#include <QMainWindow>

class QPushButton;
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget* parent = 0);
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event);
private:
    QPushButton* m_CurrentButton;
};
```

**MainWindow.cpp**:

```
#include <QEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPushButton>
#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    auto widget = new QWidget(this);
    auto addButton = new QPushButton("add", widget);
    setCentralWidget(widget);
    addButton->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
{
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        m_CurrentButton = new QPushButton("new", centralWidget());
        auto localPoint = mapFromGlobal(mouseEvent->globalPos());
        m_CurrentButton->move(localPoint);
        m_CurrentButton->show();
        return true;
    }
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseMove)
    {
        auto mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(event);
        auto localPoint = mapFromGlobal(mouseEvent->globalPos());
        m_CurrentButton->move(localPoint);
        return true;
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

На базе этого кода, Вы можете адаптировать свой код.

Answer (score 0):

предложу необычный вариант:
- AddButton сделать наследником от GreenButton
- Как только AddButton кликнули, что означает добавление, AddButton меняет своё рисование, на рисование предка. То есть, начинает рисоваться, как GreenButton.
- Новый AddButton на месте старого можно сделать как в начале таскания, так и по его окончанию - зависит от сценария